# Get the ID node from coordinates PYTHON OSMNX

Tags: python, osmnx

I'm currently trying to get the ID node from this coordinates (-70.74213872499999, -33.411204874999996). I was using the ox.get_nearest_node() function, but unfortunately i realized it is deprecated. There is any alternative i can use? The coordinates are not an exact node, because they are product from the average of other nodes.

```
lugar = 'Provincia de Santiago, Chile'
city = ox.graph_from_place(lugar)
ox.get_nearest_node(city, (-70.74213872499999, -33.411204874999996))
```

Comment: share valid python code please

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal, reproducible example to allow others to troubleshoot and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an alternative, as the deprecation warning states:

> UserWarning: The `get_nearest_node` function has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use the more efficient `distance.nearest_nodes` instead.

So, use [nearest_nodes](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes) instead:

```py
ox.nearest_nodes(G, -70.74213872499999, -33.411204874999996)
```